# Rails incorrectly generates route for a resource with :controller set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So here's the routes in question:

```
  resources :subjects, path: 'library' do
    resources :modules, controller: 'subject_modules'
  end
```

When I write `form_for [@subject, @subject_module]` (with those two set to what you'd expect), Rails tries to generate "subject_subject_module_path".

When I remove the `:path` for the subjects resource, the generated helper remains the same (as expected).

What it should be is "subject_module_path"; I suspect the problem is that Rails looks at the controller for the modules resources and uses that instead of its actual path, i.e. it builds this helper:

**subject_** + **subject_module_** + path

From what I've gathered so far, it's pointing towards the possibility of a bug, but is it possible it's more something on my side or something intended by design?

For now, I suppose this is usable as a temporary fix:

```
form_for([@subject, @subject_module], url: subject_module_path(@subject, @subject_module))
```

I'm using Rails 3.1.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that occurs due to the design of Rails.

The following is what the Rails API docs say in relation to [`url_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-url_for-label-Relying+on+named+routes):

> #### Relying on named routes
>
> Passing a record (like an Active Record or Active Resource) instead of
>   a Hash as the options parameter will trigger the named route for that
>   record. The lookup will happen on the name of the class. So passing a
>   Workshop object will attempt to use the workshop_path route. If you
>   have a nested route, such as admin_workshop_path you’ll have to call
>   that explicitly (it’s impossible for url_for to guess that route).

But saying explicitly declaring a helper is required when you have a "nested route" is in accurate. If the nesting occurs under a **resource** (without certain kinds of routing options, more on this later), Rails will be able to generate the path without any issues.

`form_for` appears to at some point, like `url_for`, call [`polymorphic_url`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes/polymorphic_url) in order to generate the URL to target, which in turn calls [`build_named_route_call`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes/build_named_route_call).

You can see that `build_named_route_call` simply generates underscored_versions of the ModelNames passed in, and joins them together with underscores.

Bringing that back to my routing:

```
  resources :subjects, path: 'library' do
    resources :modules, controller: 'subject_modules'
  end
```

Since the *subjects* resource is under /library/ by setting `:path`, its helpers remain as `subjects_*`, and thus Rails has no problems generating a URL for it when passed a `Subject`. The `subject_modules` resource (named as such since Rails reserves the name Module for models) however, **has had its named helpers changed from its model name** through the setting of `:controller`.

Mystery solved.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a form (update or create) then your routes should be pointing to

`subjects_module_path`

which should generate the URL

`/library/modules/`

have you tried pointing your form at

`form_for [:subjects, @subject_module]`?

which will then end up at your subject_modules controller

To be honest, your naming is very confusing and probably not helping.  Ideally `subject_modules` should just be `modules`.

Comment: I did actually try to use `modules` but it seems to be reserved by Rails :( I just tried `form_for [:subjects, @subject_module]` and it seems to cause the same helper to be generated. The intended URL is `/library/2/modules/1`.